# Compatibility of 9-Speed Alivio Rear Shifter with a 9-Speed Deore Rear Derailleur

Tags: derailleur, shifter

Is a 9-speed Alivio rear shifter compatible with a 9-speed Deore rear derailleur?

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

As a rule, you can take any 7, 8, or 9 speed Shimano rear derailleur and use it with a 7, 8, or 9 speed Shimano rear shifter.  It is when you venture to 10-speed and beyond that things get a little more complicated.